# laravel upgrade to 5.7 from 5.6 composer not working

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.6, laravel-upgrade

I am upgrading my laravel project to 5.6. current version is 5.5.38. my composer file is as below. when i run composer update, it does nothing but showing **Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)** in the terminal for hours. what would be the issue for this?

```
"require": {
    "php":">=7.1.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "fideloper/proxy" : "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "v2.1.*",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
    "anchu/ftp": "dev-master",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "1.20",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
    "regulus/activity-log": "0.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1",
    "filp/whoops" : "~2.0"

},
```

Comment: "laravel upgrade to 5.6 from 5.7" Upgrading / Downgrading? Can you please clear this point?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince: my mistake mate. upgrading to 5.7 from 5.6

Comment: Anyhow I found out what was the issue. issue was my PHP version. I updated vagrant PHP version to the newest and ran composer update and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster fixed this by upgrading PHP, but for others (at time of writing, Laravel 5.5 is still the LTS version, so there will be many people upgrading from that soon), should Composer hang forever (as it did for me, despite running PHP 7.3):

- A tip is to remove the entire `require-dev` section (the one that is only used on your dev environment) and see if it works, than add the packages back in again one at a time – on doing that, you might get an error like this with subsequent Composer commands (or more specifically, the *Artisan* commands, such as `clear-compiled`, that are launched by Composer):

> In Application.php line 637:
>
> Class 'Laracasts\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found

…in which case, you probably need to comment out the appropriate line in *app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php::register()* - also, try `composer dump-autoload`.

**Another very useful option: `composer-update --no-scripts`**

- Laravel 5.6 now uses Symfony 4, not 3 (so you might switch to "~4.3")
- There are some Symfony 4 requirements: https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/reference/requirements.html

Commit your existing copies of `composer.json` and `composer.lock` before you start, to make it easy to see what you've changed.